# Spring Kafka Test with Confluent Kafka Avro Serializer cannot find ZKClientConfig

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, avro, spring-kafka

I struggle with starting embedded Kafka for intergration testing. This error is displayed:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedKafka': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/zookeeper/client/ZKClientConfig

This is my minimal sample. I need to use `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` as long as I need to autowire further Spring beans.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@EmbeddedKafka(
        partitions = 1,
        bootstrapServersProperty = "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers")
public class KafkaTest {

    @Test
    public void test(EmbeddedKafkaBroker broker) {
        var brokerList = broker.getBrokersAsString();
        log.debug("Embedded Kakfa topics {}", broker.getTopics());
    }
}
```

I use:

- Java 11
- Spring Boot 2.3
- jUnit 5

My guess the dependency inconsistence takes the place here, however, it is weird since I believe Spring Boot parent can achieve the dependencies compatibility.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

For sure, I list related dependencies in **pom.xml** below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3</version>
</dependency>

<!-- TEST SCOPE -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I tried to exclude `org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients` in both `org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test` and `io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer` with no luck and the same error ocurred.

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

Comment: You are correct; Boot should wire in the correct dependencies; take a look at your class path and make sure all the jars have the same versions - see [here for the complete list](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#deps-for-24x).

Comment: @GaryRussell: The required dependencies matches. The problem is that `io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer` includes jars that are not sufficient for `org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

These dependencies are in clash:

- `io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:5.2.3`
- `org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:jar:2.5.0.RELEASE`
- ... from the parent `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.3.0.RELEASE`

The former one uses `org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.13:compile` which should be excluded:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
            <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

**Long answer:**

Inspecing `mvn dependency:tree` before shows that `kafka-avro-serializer` includes surprisingly `org.apache.zookeeper` dependency while `spring-kafka-test` doesn't:

Extracted for **kafka-avro-serializer**

```
[INFO] +- io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:jar:5.2.3:compile  
[INFO] |  +- io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-client:jar:5.2.3:compile    
[INFO] |  +- io.confluent:common-config:jar:5.2.3:compile   
[INFO] |  \- io.confluent:common-utils:jar:5.2.3:compile    
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.13:compile   
[INFO] |     |  +- jline:jline:jar:0.9.94:compile   
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.yetus:audience-annotations:jar:0.5.0:compile  
[INFO] |     |  \- io.netty:netty:jar:3.10.6.Final:compile  
[INFO] |     \- com.101tec:zkclient:jar:0.10:compile
```

Extracted for **spring-kafka-test**

```
[INFO] \- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:jar:2.5.0.RELEASE:test    
[INFO]    +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:test:2.5.0:test 
[INFO]    +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:jar:2.5.0:test  
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.kafka:connect-json:jar:2.5.0:test    
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.kafka:connect-api:jar:2.5.0:test  
[INFO]    |  \- org.rocksdb:rocksdbjni:jar:5.18.3:test  
[INFO]    +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams-test-utils:jar:2.5.0:test   
[INFO]    +- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.12:jar:2.5.0:test 
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.12:jar:2.11.0:test  
[INFO]    |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-paranamer:jar:2.11.0:test    
[INFO]    |  |     \- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.8:test 
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:jar:2.11.0:test 
[INFO]    |  +- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:5.0.4:test   
[INFO]    |  +- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.2.0:test  
[INFO]    |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-collection-compat_2.12:jar:2.1.3:test  
[INFO]    |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat_2.12:jar:0.9.0:test   
[INFO]    |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.12.10:test   
[INFO]    |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.12.10:test   
[INFO]    |  +- com.typesafe.scala-logging:scala-logging_2.12:jar:3.9.2:test    
[INFO]    |  \- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.4:test    
[INFO]    +- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.12:jar:test:2.5.0:test    
[INFO]    \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.6.2:test 
[INFO]       +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test  
[INFO]       +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test    
[INFO]       \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.6.2:test
```

The `spring-kafka-test` is missing `org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper` therefore the test cannot connect to Zookeeper and error is shown:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedKafka': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/zookeeper/client/ZKClientConfig

Excluding such dependency from `kafka-avro-serializer` fixes the problem (see the **Short Answer**). The ouptut of `mvn dependency:tree` confirms the `org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper` is properly excluded from `kafka-avro-serializer` and included in `spring-kafka-test`.

Extracted for **kafka-avro-serializer**:

```
+- io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:jar:5.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-client:jar:5.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.confluent:common-config:jar:5.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.confluent:common-utils:jar:5.2.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.101tec:zkclient:jar:0.10:compile
```

Extracted for **spring-kafka-test**:

```
\- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:jar:2.5.0.RELEASE:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:test:2.5.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:jar:2.5.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.kafka:connect-json:jar:2.5.0:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.kafka:connect-api:jar:2.5.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.rocksdb:rocksdbjni:jar:5.18.3:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams-test-utils:jar:2.5.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.12:jar:2.5.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.12:jar:2.11.0:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-paranamer:jar:2.11.0:test
[INFO]    |  |     \- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.8:test
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:jar:2.11.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO]    |  +- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-collection-compat_2.12:jar:2.1.3:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat_2.12:jar:0.9.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.12.10:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.12.10:test
[INFO]    |  +- com.typesafe.scala-logging:scala-logging_2.12:jar:3.9.2:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.5.7:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper-jute:jar:3.5.7:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.yetus:audience-annotations:jar:0.5.0:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.49.Final:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.49.Final:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.49.Final:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.49.Final:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.49.Final:test
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.49.Final:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:4.1.49.Final:test
[INFO]    |  |     \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.49.Final:test
[INFO]    |  \- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.4:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.12:jar:test:2.5.0:test
[INFO]    \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.6.2:test
[INFO]       +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO]       +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO]       \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.6.2:test
```

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add some information to the previous answer, because i ran into a similar problem today.

The main issue is that the kafka-client 2.5.0 is relying on Zookeeper 3.5 and no longer Zookeeper 3.4 (see https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka for compatibiliy matrix)

The ZkClientConfig class has been introduced in Zookeeper 3.5.2
So any Zookeeper version below this will provoke this error.
For testing purpose, you need to remove any zookeeper dependency already present and below 3.5.2 and add post 3.5.2 to your test dependencies.